# How to put ads between mysql results?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to put ads after every 4 results (mysql results) for example.

I use for loop to pass to the next line after every 2 results. and I use also pagination code to echo every 10 results in different page.
now I need to insert ads between the results. how?

This is my code :-

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die (mysql_error ());


    mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");



 $tbl_name="mytable";  //your table name
 // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
 $adjacents = 3;

 /* 
    First get total number of rows in data table. 
    If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
 */
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM mytable WHERE department like 'mytopic'";
 $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

 /* Setup vars for query. */
 $targetpage = "mypage.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
 $limit = 10;         //how many items to show per page
 $page = $_GET['page'];

 if($page) 
  $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;    //first item to display on this page
 else
  $start = 0;        //if no page var is given, set start to 0

 /* Get data. */
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE department like 'mytopic' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 /* Setup page vars for display. */
 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;     //if no page var is given, default to 1.
 $prev = $page - 1;       //previous page is page - 1
 $next = $page + 1;       //next page is page + 1
 $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
 $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;      //last page minus 1

 /* 
  Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
  We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
 */
 $pagination = "";
 if($lastpage > 1)
 { 
  $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
  //previous button
  if ($page > 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">« previous</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« previous</span>"; 

  //pages 
  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
  { 
   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
   {
    if ($counter == $page)
     $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
    else
     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&department=mytopic\">$counter</a>";     
   }
  }
  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
  {
   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  
   {
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //in middle; hide some front and some back
   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //close to end; only hide early pages
   else
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
   }
  }

  //next button
  if ($page < $counter - 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next »</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";
  $pagination.= "</div>\n";  
 }
?>
 <?php

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  // Your while loop here

$myimage[] = $row['icon_image'];
$mybook[]= $row['book'];
$mywriter[]= $row['writer'];
$myid[]=$row['id'];
}

echo '<table><tr>';
for($x=0;$x<count($myimage)&&count($mybook)&&count($mywriter);$x++) {
if ($x%2==0) { echo '</tr>'; }

echo "<td>";
        echo "<div id='con_loop'>";
        echo "<div id='con_image'>";
if($myimage[$x])
{
        echo "<a href=\"/download.php?id={$myid[$x]}\">"."<img alt={$mybook[$x]} src={$myimage[$x]}>"."</a>"." ";
}
else
{
        echo "<a href=\"/download.php?id={$myid[$x]}\">"."<img src='/images/icon_image.png'>"."</a>"." ";
}
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id='con_name'>";
        echo " "."<a class='abook' href=\"/download.php?id={$myid[$x]}\">{$mybook[$x]}</a>"." ";
        echo "<br>"."<br>";
        echo " "."<a class='awriter' href=\"/download.php?id={$myid[$x]}\">{$mywriter[$x]}</a>"." ";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";


echo "</td>";

}
?>
</table>
<?=$pagination?>
```

Comment: so put in a counter `if ($row++ % 4 == 0) { show ad; }`

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to answer this, as its only a partial answer, 
You want to do a Foreach loop for a count of 4, and your foreach would be on the statement your looping.

The Count would be something like:

```
$count = 1;
foreach( $BAR as $FOO) 
{
    if ($count%4 == 1)
        {  
             echo "YOURADDHERE";
        }
    if ($count%4 == 0)
    {
             echo "END OF ADD";
    }
    $count++;
```

I wanted to post this as a comment, As i cannot run it against your code.

Comment: Can anyone help me with a fit script to proportion my code?